# Multiple capybara "visit" in the same block returns an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara

In the project I'm using

```
gem 'capybara'
gem 'capybara-selenium'
```

If I have a block like this:

```
it do
  array.each do |elem|
    visit some_path(elem)
    expect(page).to have_text(/RecordNotFound/i)
  end
end
```

where the first `visit` returns 404-page, then next `visit` do not work, but return an  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError
unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this on my tests when visiting absolute paths.
If the path you're trying to visit is on your local server, try making it into a relative path by e.g. splitting the string. For example:

"http://localhost:3000/users/password/new" => "/users/password/new"